# Finding largest sequence of equal elements in an array

Tags: php, arrays

So suppose I have this array of five elements. I need to find those that repeat the most often and are in a sequence.

```
$array = array('one','five','five','five','four');
```

The expected output is: `five` since it's the largest sequence of equal elements. How do I find those elements or moreover compare their values so I can figure which ones are repeated?

```
foreach ($array as $element) { #find repeating elements }
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I don't know what to try duh? That's why I asked. Keep downvoting.

Comment: You know what you want: The longest sequence. So why not get each sequence and then compare their length? Don't know how? Be creative! Believe me, if you want to learn how to solve this, you need to put effort into it. If you want it solved, hire someone. Also try to see my point: To me it looks like you typed this question in <1min and nothing more. Why should I waste my time if you're not willing to do the same?

Comment: Step through the array. Is this element the same as the last one? Increment a counter. Is it different? Is the element counter higher than the current longest sequence? Then this sequence is longer.

Comment: array_count_values()?

Comment: Could you add some example input and output please.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda like a brute approach. Somewhat like kingkero cited. Example:

```
$array = array('one','one','one','five','five','five','five','five','four','four', 'one','four');
$prev = '';
$sequences = array();

// group them
foreach($array as $value) {
    if(!isset($sequences[$value])) {
        $sequences[$value][] = 0;
        $prev = $value;
    }

    if($prev == $value) {
        $val = array_pop($sequences[$value]) + 1;
        $sequences[$value][] = $val;
    } else {
        $prev = $value;
        $sequences[$value][] = 1;
    }

}
```

Sequences will look like:

```
Array
(
    [one] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
        )

    [five] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
        )

    [four] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```

---

```
// identify
$data['key_with_the_most'] = '';
$data['consecutive_pattern'] = 0;
foreach($sequences as $key => $value) {
    if(max($value) > $data['consecutive_pattern']) {
        $data['consecutive_pattern'] = max($value);
        $data['key_with_the_most'] = $key;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

`$data` outputs to:

```
Array
(
    [key_with_the_most] => five
    [consecutive_pattern] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by this way. I think it will fill your demand!

```
$array = array('one','five','five','five','four');
$counts = array_count_values($array);
$max = 0; $key = '';
foreach($counts as $k=>$v){
    if($v > $max)
    {
        $max = $v;
        $key = $k;
    }
}
echo $key;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array  = ['a','b','b','c'];
$counts = array_count_values($array);
arsort($counts);
print key($counts);
```

Output:

```
b
```

Comment: If input is `['a','b','c','b','c','d','d','c']` this outputs `c`, whereas I think the OP would want `d`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming inputs could have multiple sequences with the same number of items:

```
<?php
$array = ['a','a','b','b','c','b'];

$grouped = [];
$last = null;
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    if($last !== $v)
        $i = $k;
    $grouped[$i][] = $last = $v;
}

print_r($grouped);

$counted_groups = array_map('count', $grouped);
arsort($counted_groups);

print_r($counted_groups);

$max_consecutives = [];
$max_occurences   = current($counted_groups);
$max_counted_keys = array_keys($counted_groups, $max_occurences);
foreach($max_counted_keys as $counted_groups_key)
    $max_consecutives[] =
        [
            'item' => $array[$counted_groups_key],
            'no_repeats' => $max_occurences,
            'from_index' => $counted_groups_key
        ];

print_r($max_consecutives);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => a
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => b
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => a
            [no_repeats] => 2
            [from_index] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => b
            [no_repeats] => 2
            [from_index] => 2
        )

)
```